# How to bind to template-generated elements in a ListView

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, gridview

I have a ListView where for each item I'd like to add a TextBox for user input, and then be able bind to its content per selected item (or using an indexer) from outside of the ListView.

To illustrate:

```
     <ListView Name="lv" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource lvSrc1}}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridView.Columns>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Loc">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox Name="tbGv" Text="User input" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView.Columns>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>



<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=lv, Path=SelectedItem[tbGv]}" />
```

Of course the above binding won't work, as SelectedItem returns an object from the underlying collection, which has nothing to do with the added TextBox.

How can I access the generated TextBoxes using *pure XAML*?

**Edit:**
I've now found a couple of posts with somewhat similar problems, where solutions presented are trickier than I expected and not based on XAML.

So rather, would it be possible to access ListViewItem (not the data its bound to) and its properties? This way I think I could pass text from my TextBox through the Tag property of ListViewItem.

I'm quite new to WPF so I assume that my problem and its phrasing is ridiculous, but please be gentle ;)

Comment: It is hard to tell what the issue is, without knowing about your view models and the definitions of `lvSrc1`, `TX60` ot `tbGv`. How do you set your data context?

Comment: Part of the point is that I'm  not  trying to access any object from the collection behind lvSrc, so I'd like  lvSrc to be irrelevant. I only need to somehow bind to the content of TextBoxes generated by the CellTemplate. These are for user input.
I removed the TX60 column to make it cleaner.